# How do I assign values from a Textfile with BufferedReader from a specific line?

Tags: java, if-statement, variable-assignment, bufferedreader, reader

```
package inputOutput;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test_leser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // asking which file to open (no abändre das es dynamisch übere Browser funktioniert)
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Filename ");
    BufferedReader bReader = null;

    // Open demanded file
    try {
        bReader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\valat\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\image-data\\" + scan.next()));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
        System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage());
        // Programm geht nicht weiter, falls file not found
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String line;
    String resolution = null;
    String image = null;
    String description = null;
    int i   = 0;

    // assigning values to variables
    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {

        // zähler
        i += 1;

        if (line.startsWith("description:")) {
                description = line;
        }

        else if (line.startsWith("image-file")) {

            image = line;
        }

        else if (line.startsWith("resolution:")) {
            resolution = line;

        } else {
            System.out.println("something is REALLY wrong");
        }

        System.out.println(description);
        System.out.println(image);
        System.out.println(resolution);
    }

}
```

}

Hey. I'm having trouble here.
I'm reading this text with a BufferedReader from a textfile:

```
description: Blutausstrich (Mensch)
image-file: image01.jpg
resolution: 0.002 mm
```

after that my next intention is to iterate through each line, and assign each line on its own to a variable.
The problem is, my output, whenever I try it, is the following:

```
description: Blutausstrich (Mensch)
null
null
description: Blutausstrich (Mensch)
image-file: image01.jpg
null
description: Blutausstrich (Mensch)
image-file: image01.jpg
resolution: 0.002 mm
```

As you can probably see, that isn't exactly what I want. How can I assign just the specific lines which fullfill my if-condition from the txtfile with my variables? I would really appreciate some help, I'm trying to play aroung with this one for hours, I looked up so many different things, and I'm pretty sure it's a pretty obvious answer which will make me think "oh bloody hell, seriously? I'm a moron".

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Well.. yeah. Just move the Output out of the while-loop. Your assignment is not the problem. But that it is printed after every line (so not all variables have been assigned after the first two lines)

Comment: oh for god's sake, I KNEW I was a morron. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move stdout out of while loop:

```
        System.out.println(description);
        System.out.println(image);
        System.out.println(resolution);
```

The problem is we are printing before assignment of all the variables.

Cheers !

Comment: Thank you! I pretty much predicted it: after getting the answer, I'd realise how much of a morron I was haha

Comment: @Nilfgaardian no probem :)